# Cocoapods and ruby_executable_hooks: no such file or directory

Tags: ios, build, rubygems, cocoapods

I'm using Roboto.build software to have automated builds for ios. I have set it up on one iMac, where all works fine. However, on my second machine I encountered following error, when trying to make a build:

```
Podfile found, but no Pods directory...performing pod install...
env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory
```

Normally pod update/pod installs commands work fine for me. I have my pod installed in

```
/$HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/pod
```

and created symlink

```
/usr/bin/pod
```

I read other topic regarding this ruby_executable_hooks error, but solutions provided there does not help. I'm sure it's related with cocopads/gems configuration but have no idea where to look. Hope, you can suggest me something.

Best,

Answer (score 1):

**FIXED SOLUTION**

Run below command in `terminal` to refresh `executable-hooks`.

```
sudo gem install --user-install executable-hooks
```

and then run . `pod install`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try:

```
sudo gem update --system
```